# Call a function from another contract, entirely determined by initial contract's function arguments

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation

I would like to have a contract `MainContract` that can call any other contract functions depending on arguments given a `MainContract` function. It would look like this:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.16;

contract MainContract{

    function callAnotherFunctionOfAnyContract(bytes[] calldata neededData, ..?) public {
        //Use neededData to call the described function (anyFunction in this example)
    }
}

contract AnyOtherContract{
    MainContract mainContract = MainContract(0x...)

    function callMainContract() public {
        bytes[] memory neededData;
        neededData = ??; //Set neededData so that it calls the anyFunction below from the mainContract
        mainContract.callAnotherFunctionOfAnyContract(neededData, ..?);
    }

    function anyFunction(address parameter1, uint256 parameter2, ...) public {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

So what I'm looking for is a way for the `callMainContract` function to provide `callAnotherFunctionOfAnyOtherContract` what it needs to call the `anyFunction` from there, and for the `callAnotherFunctionOfAnyOtherContract` function to finally call `anyFunction`. Note that in this case the `anyFunction` is in the same contract as the initial function, but that is just to simplify the example, it could be from any other deployed contract. The important point is that there is no need for the `MainContract` to know the contract it's calling (if that is even possible in current Solidity), so it can work with any contract as long as the correct data is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all the needed parameters for the call in a `bytes neededData` argument, then make the call like this:

```
(bool success, ) = targetContract.call(neededData);
```

To encode `neededData` you can use `abi.encodeWithSignature()`, like so:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.16;

contract MainContract{

    function callAnotherFunctionOfAnyContract(address targetContract, bytes calldata neededData) public {
        (bool success, ) = targetContract.call(neededData);
        require(success, "Call failed");
    }
}

contract AnyOtherContract{
    MainContract mainContract = MainContract(0x...)

    function callMainContract() public {
        address targetContract = ...;  // the contract to call

        address param1 = ...; uint256 param2 = ...;
        bytes memory neededData = abi.encodeWithSignature("anyFunction(address,uint256)", param1, param2);
        mainContract.callAnotherFunctionOfAnyContract(targetContract, neededData);
    }

    function anyFunction(address parameter1, uint256 parameter2) public {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As `anyFunction()` can be a function of any contract, so you need to have address of that contract.
Seems like `neededData` provided by `callMainContract` should have an address field which will be the contract address of target contract with `anyFunction`. So lets say there is a `TargetContract` which has `anyFunction` then code required...
Now in `MainContract` -

```
function callAnotherFunctionOfAnyContract(bytes[] calldata neededData, ..?) public {
        (address targetContract, address parameter1, uint256 parameter2, ...) = abi.decode(neededData, (address, address, uint256, ...));
        TargetContract targetContractInstance = TargetContract(targetContract);
        targetContractInstance.anyFunction(parameter1,parameter2, ...); 
    }
```

Note: `anyFunction` definition in targetContract should be fixed ie the number of parameters it has cant be dynamic, as you will also be required to provide interface for anyFunction's targetContract.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My goal is to avoid the need of knowing the other contract. So I wanted to know if it was possible to do so without having the other contract interface, by providing everything in the `callAnotherFunctionOfAnyContract` arguments (which function to call, from which contract and with which argument(s)), so that literally any contract function could be executed by going through the `MainContract`.

Comment: ok... now i get it. Happy to see you found your answer